# protect my public folder from direct access using htaccess rules

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am new to PHP. I am using codeignitor, just want to protect my **public** folder from direct access.  e.g. Refer below url. when i enter this URL in browser on my local machine it shows all my static files.

http://localhost/myapp/public/

This is htaccess file content. So could you please help how i protect my public folder from direct access.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will turn off directory listings.

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal or SSH

```
chmod 750 <folderName>
```

Blocks the folder from Loading in browser ie blocking public access

Answer (score 0):

In the directory, create a plain text file that you name .htaccess and put this line in it:

deny from all

Comment: after this not able to open my static files thru application when user is accessing it